# Prevent leaving combobox if validate fails

Tags: winforms, delphi, validation, combobox

I have a combobox that has items in it and I want to prevent the cursor from being able to leave the control if it fails a validation check (namely for valid file names). Basically the cursor can leave if the file is found.

I assume this needs to be done during the OnExit event.

How do I bring the focus back to the control if the validate conditions are not met?

Comment: I'm not sure your users will appreciate this feature. It might happen, for instance, that your application is not the only application they run at the moment. Perhaps their alarm clock application starts beeping, and the alarm clock's big 'Snooze' button is a few hundred pixels away from the cursor. Then the user will be pretty angry if he cannot move the cursor from your checkbox.

Comment: What validation framework are you using? If it is jQuery validation then there is a function called focusInvalid()

Comment: @achakravarty: It is not. This is Win32 Delphi programming, not HTML+JS.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand that should only be a consideration if there was an alarm clock on my form, the user can switch between applications as normal. this a simple form, just to make sure that we don't continue if it's not possible. what else do you suggest? a label informing the user what's wrong?

Comment: Yes I think an error message is a better way to go rather than not allowing the user to move.

Comment: You might consider to use actions enabling further steps e.g. `procedure TForm1.NextStepButtonActionUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
     TAction(Sender).Enabled := FileExists(FileNameBox.Text)
end;`

Comment: @ika - Andreas probably assumed you meant 'cursor' when you said 'cursor', what you meant probably was 'caret'. Then again, what you probably actually meant should be 'focus'.

Comment: Your users will hate you. But if you are prepared to suffer that, call `SetFocus` on the control that you want to receive focus.

Comment: @KenWhite ... winforms tag is for .Net right? this question is for Delphi right? in that case... (:-D)